# Pgfplot, new dash pattern with star?

Tags: pgfplots, pattern

Pgfplots use only dots in the pattern (`dashdotted`, `dashdotdotted`). If I use mark option the marks do not seem to compatible with the rest of the line. Is it possible to use `star` (suitably sized) or `square` etc. instead of `dot`.

It is like

```
dashdotted: -.-.-    
dashdotdotted: -..-..-..    
dashstar: -*-*-*    
dashstarstar: -**-**-**
```

Comment: What does "not compatible with the rest of the line" mean? You could perhaps use the `decorations.markings` library of TikZ.

Comment: dashes coincide marks somewhere and dots coincide marks somewhere else. I can not see sequential `-*-*-*` pattern on the line.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. That should be no surprise, markers and dash patterns are not really related to each other in that sense.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am just wondering why you deleted your answer. To me it looks good, but most likely I am missing something obvious.

Comment: @marmot It breaks down quite quickly for functions more complicated than a straight line, at least the `dashstarstar`. Didn't work with a sine function, or x^3 for example.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. But the problem seems only to be the starstar thing, and with `dashstarstar/.style={
 dash pattern=on 5pt off 10pt,
 postaction={
  decorate,
  decoration={
   markings,
   mark=between positions 7.5pt and 1 step 15pt with {
     \node at (0pt,0pt) {\pgfuseplotmark{star}};
  \node at (4pt,0pt) {\pgfuseplotmark{star}};
   },
  }
 }
}`, i.e. just one mark directive, it seems to work nicely. (I think it is just the statement on p. 585 of the pgfmanual that the positions need to increase.)

Comment: @marmot A bit better perhaps, but that will not work properly if the two marks are near a sharp turn in the line, because they are placed along the same tangent. Anyways, I'll edit a bit and undelete.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, I think you should undelete your nice answer. And I guess one could mitigate the problem somewhat by putting the stars at `(-2pt,0)` and `(2pt,0)` and adjusting the dash phase accordingly.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. One more proposal: introduce `\newcounter{moviestar}` and do `dashstarstar/.style={
 dash pattern=on 4pt off 8pt,
 postaction={
  decorate,
  decoration={
   markings,
   mark=at position 0 with {\setcounter{moviestar}{0}},
   mark=between positions 6pt and 1 step 4pt with {
   \stepcounter{moviestar}
   \coordinate (moviestar-\themoviestar);
   \ifnum\themoviestar=3
    \node at (moviestar-1) {\pgfuseplotmark{star}};
 \node at (moviestar-2) {\pgfuseplotmark{star}};
 \setcounter{moviestar}{0}
   \fi 
   },
  }
 }
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, it might be possible to make use of a `markings` decoration here. Below I defined a couple of example styles, one borrowed from marmot's comments to your question. A custom `dash pattern` is used to get a known distance between dashes, and the decoration is used to place the marks in the gaps.

They might not work properly for all plots, it doesn't, on my computer at least, work with the `smooth` option (dimension too large-error), and it has to be tailored to specific mark sizes. But it might be useful.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\tikzset{
dashstar/.style={
 dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt,
 postaction={
  decorate,
  decoration={
   markings,
   mark=between positions 7.5pt and 1 step 10pt with {
     \node {\pgfuseplotmark{star}};
   }
  }
 }
},
dashstarstar/.style={ % from marmot's comments
 dash pattern=on 5pt off 10pt,
 postaction={
   decorate,
   decoration={
     markings,
     mark=between positions 10pt and 1
          step 15pt
           with {
            \node at (-2pt,0pt) {\pgfuseplotmark{star}};
            \node at (2pt,0pt) {\pgfuseplotmark{star}};
           }
   }
 }
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
   \addplot [dashstar,samples=200] {sin(x*180/pi)};
   \addplot [dashstarstar] {1.1};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very modest extension to [Torbjørn T.' nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437661/121799) that works with `smooth` or a large number of samples, but not with both at the same time. The difference is that the decorations are implemented at a lower level (at least I believe that is the case).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{stars}{initial}{\state{initial}[width=6pt,next state=star1]
{
}
\state{star1}[width=4pt,next state=gap]
{
   \pgfuseplotmark{star}
  }
\state{gap}[width=4pt,next state=star1]
{
  }
\state{final}
{
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
}  

}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{starstars}{initial}{\state{initial}[width=6pt,next state=star1]
{
}
\state{star1}[width=4pt,next state=star2]
{
   \pgfuseplotmark{star}
}
\state{star2}[width=4pt,next state=gap]
{
   \pgfuseplotmark{star}
  }
\state{gap}[width=4pt,next state=star1]
{
  }
\state{final}
{
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
}  
}
\tikzset{
dashStar/.style={dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt,postaction={decorate,decoration=stars}},
dashStarStar/.style={dash pattern=on 4pt off 8pt,postaction={decorate,decoration=starstars}},
}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[dashStar,samples=100] {sin(x*180/pi)};
    \addplot[dashStarStar,smooth] {cos(x*720/pi)};
   \legend{$\sin(x)$,$\cos(x)$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]